# How can I extract the docker filesystem into my local filesystem so I no longer have to use docker

Tags: docker, containers

I have a docker container that I downloaded from docker hub that has an entire filesystem inside it. Due to certain reasons, I want to remove all the files from inside the container and recreate the filesystem on my local machine.

I can't run the image as a container on it's own for more than a few seconds because it relies on some other commands.

**THINGS I HAVE TRIED:**

- I have seen answers with docker export and docker save but both of these are giving me a tarball which has 20-30 folders inside it, each of which has a tar directory inside. I do not want to manually go in and do this.
- I wrote a simple bash script that helped me remove the files from .tar to a simple directory  `for d in ./*/ ; do (cd "$d" && tar xvf ./*.tar); done`. This gave me a mess of files that I would have to build into a filesystem on my own.

Comment: Do you have the image's Dockerfile; can you follow the steps there manually to recreate the image in some other environment?

Comment: @DavidMaze where can I find my DockerFile?

Comment: I think you have an image, try `docker run -td yourimage` the container will start without exit, from here you can use `docker cp` for copy files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the image has the `tar` command available, you can run:

```
docker run --rm yourimage tar -C / -cf- | tar -C /path/to/root -xf-
```

This will tar up the contents up the image, and then untar it on your host in the location of your choice (`/path/to/root` in the above example).

---

I once wrote a tool called [undocker](https://github.com/larsks/undocker) for extracting a docker image to a local directory; you would use it like this:

```
docker save myimage | undocker
```

I haven't used it much in the past several years, but it seems to work on a few test images. This is useful if you're trying to extract the contents of an image in which you can't run `tar`.